# Count rows grouped by condition in SQL

Tags: sql

We have a table like this:

```
+----+--------+
| Id | ItemId |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 1100   |
| 1  | 1101   |
| 1  | 1102   |
| 2  | 2001   |
| 2  | 2002   |
| 3  | 1101   |
+----+--------+
```

We want to count how many items each guy has, and show the guys with 2 items or more. Like this:

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | ItemCount |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | 3         |
| 2  | 2         |
+----+-----------+
```

We didn't count the guy with Id = 3 because he's got only 1 item.

How can we do this in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(itemId) AS ItemCount 
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(itemId) > 1
```

Comment: Am I the only one in the world that prefers `Count(*) >= 2`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
       count(1)
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
GROUP  BY id
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```

Comment: In Oracle it counts only one column. It did matter in Oracle8 (performance) but now it does not matter. Of course you can use count(*) or count(itemId).

Comment: count(1) is just an habit, you can use count(*) or count(-42) it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM (    
    SELECT COUNT(ItemId ) AS COUNT, Id FROM ITEM 
    GROUP BY Id 
) 

my_select
WHERE COUNT>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id, count(ItemId) as ItemCount
   from table_name 
   group by Id 
   having ItemCount > 1
```

Comment: you can't do that. You have to filter the rows, then aggregate. But you try to do a filter on the result of an aggregate. The keyword to use is *HAVING*, take a look at my answer